# Php form won't post results when filled out

Tags: php, html, if-statement, refresh, calculator

First of all, I am not en expert at programming, so please explain things a bit if you can so I can understand them better. I am trying to make a calculator that will have some fields the user can fill out, and will display the last output. Basically this:

Variable boxes
"Go" button
Results display here after Go is pressed.

And the user can change the boxes and click go again to refresh with the new results.

I do not want to use Java for this if at all possible. Please help me with an HTML/PHP solution.

I have this page nammed "isset.php"

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
        $a = $_POST['a'];
        $b = $_POST['b']; 
        $sf = $a-(2*$b);
        echo "<br><br>Safety Factor is ";
        echo $sf;
        } 
     else {
        echo "Your results will display here after you use the calculator.";
          }
 ?>

 <br>Calculator
 <form name="submit" method="post" action="isset.php">
 <table width="450px">
     <td valign="center">
     <label for="a">a</label></td>
        <td valign="center">
        <input type="text" name="a" value="45"></td></tr>
     <td valign="center">
     <label for="b">b</label></td>
        <td valign="center">
        <input type="text" name="b" value="16"></td></tr>         
 <tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
 <input type="submit" value="Calculate!">
 </td></tr></table>
 </form>        

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See prisoner's answer. the "name" parameter of an input field is what sets the post value... oh yeah, and you don't want to use javaSCRIPT. huge difference between java and javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `<input type="submit" value="Calculate!">` to `<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Calculate!">`

The reason your code is not working is because you're checking to see if the post data contains the key `submit` but you haven't defined it within your form (you do this by adding a `name` attribute).

Comment: Holy crap. That was it. you were so fast!

Comment: @user1570409 No problem. FYI on Stackoverflow, you should mark questions you ask as correct (the little tick button). This lets other users know that this was the answer to the question :)

Comment: I tried... I need to wait 10 minutes. I will once it lets me : )

Answer (score 1):

If you just change this line:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

to:

```
if(isset($_POST['a']))
```

That should see you right.

Basically you are looking for a value called 'submit', but you don't actually have a field called 'submit'. Instead you can can just check for one of the fields you do have, either 'a' or 'b'.